# hide column in display table

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

Is there any way we can hide column of display table,we have media="none" which hides the column .i have tried using

```
document.getElementById(display_column_name).media="none";
```

but it is not working, i am stuck while setting attritube of display column in javascript is there any way.As on button select column is to hide/display of display table.

i have checkbox on column header.i have to hide columns of display table.selected column is hiden on button click.

i have also tried using div tag for display column

```
<div id= "col1" style="display:block">
            <display:column paramId="date_disp" paramName="date_disp"  property="date_disp" title="Date" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" decorator="com.commons.ColDateDecorator" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;height: 25;"/>
</div>
```

and document.getElementById('col1').style.display="none"; but its not working.

Comment: you can refer this: http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uchenna is right you can use jquery library

Import the script into your page using script tag

add an attribute "id" or "class" to column you want to hide

and using that class or id you can hide that element.

eg. if you have mantioned id attribute and valuse is "abc"

then you can write :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#abc").hide();
});
```

Comment: As far as i have discover displaytag column donot take id as attribute not in <display:column> tag nor in <div> tag. So how to uniquely indentify column and hide it.My display table is displayed on passing some parameters and on check of column header that particular column is to be hidden.So please help and provide some solution. i have tried number of ways but still nothing is helpful.

Comment: @ sweety: do onething, add class attribute to your display column. lets say we are using class abc, then your display column would be  <display:column class="abc" property="name" sortable="false" title="Location Name"  />  now using jquery you can write it like this $(".abc").hide();

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply johnd,its working actually data from result set got hidden but column header was still there,i had to add headerClass attribute which then properly hide my complete column.And thanks for you introducted me to JQuery and its function.I have used toggle function which shows & hide my column.

Comment: yes you can add class  attribute to your header class also.If this solution has solved your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it one element that you want to hide or severals ? document.getElementsByName will return you an array of elements so you need to access it like this:

> document.getElementsByName(display_column_name)[0].media="none"

If it's just one element and this element has a id consider using this maybe:

```
getElementById()
```

Also i assume display_column_name is a variable defines previously right?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to this is to set the css display style to none.

```
document.getElementById("id _of_the_component").style.display = 'none';
```

Or you can use jquery Library
but you have to download jquery library from jquery.com. Import the script into your page with the script tag and do the following

```
$("#id _of_the_component).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1">TD1</td>
            <td id="td2">TD2</td>
            <td id="td3">TD3</td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("td2").style.display = "none";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vishal_Suthar3/kDb8Z/

Answer (score 0):

modify your display column like :

```
<display:column class="abc" paramId="date_disp" paramName="date_disp"  property="date_disp" title="Date" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" decorator="com.commons.ColDateDecorator" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;height: 25;"/>
```

on button click you can write :
lets say you are using button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="success" />
then you can use it like :

    $('#success').click(function(){
    $(".abc").hide();   
     });
```